# GCC 4.4.3 compiler linking issue

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

OK so I'm trying to get back c++, and started with a basic program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout << "So This Is It.";
 cout << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

And this is the result:

```
-->gcc -g -o HELLO HELLO.cpp
/tmp/ccLZLm5N.o: In function `main':
/root/Programming/Learning/C++/HELLO.cpp:9: undefined reference to `std::cout'
/root/Programming/Learning/C++/HELLO.cpp:9: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/root/Programming/Learning/C++/HELLO.cpp:10: undefined reference to `std::cout'
/root/Programming/Learning/C++/HELLO.cpp:10: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/tmp/ccLZLm5N.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccLZLm5N.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My compiler:

```
-->gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

So can I please have some information on the fix? OR. If I run into any more simple syntax problems, how do I find the correct info on this?

Comment: Try using `g++ -Wall -g` instead of `gcc -g`

Comment: Also, consider upgrading your GCC. Current version is 4.7, 4.8 is going out in a few days or weeks... Both gives quite good C++2011 support.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `gcc 4.4.3` is standard on the Ubuntu LTS 10, `gcc 4.6.3` on Ubuntu LTS 12. It's frustrating.

Comment: You may install several GCC compilers on a machine. And you definitely could compile GCC 4.8 from its source code.

Comment: you can try Beowulf Basic, translate basic code object oriented in python so you can easy programming with all python library : http://sourceforge.net/projects/beowulfpython/?source=directory

Comment: Also, use `cout << endl` instead of `cout << "\n"` (because `endl` might also flush)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used a `C` compiler instead of a `C++` compiler. `gcc` is for C, `g++` is for C++. GCC's linker will link against the C standard library, which doesn't contain the functions provided by the C++ standard library, which results in undefined references.

So use the correct `g++`:

```
g++ -g -o HELLO HELLO.cpp
```

#### Additional remark:

Usually `gcc` identifies a C++ source as such. However, it is most-likely that your Ubuntu installation doesn't have `g++` installed if you didn't install it yourself. Either ask your supervisor to install `g++` or install `g++` yourself:

```
sudu apt-get install g++
```

And since you're already installing things, get `gdb` and `valgrind` for debugging.

Comment: `gcc` is able to compile C++ code (or Fortran!). But the default linking is different (`gcc` is not linking by default the standard C++ library, but `g++` is)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: gcc is able to compile almost everything which has bee included in it's collection, I know. After all, he's getting linker errors and not compiler errors. However, I haven't eaten anything yet or drank a coffee and haven't found the correct words, and `use g++ instead of gcc` was to short for an answer, although correct ;).

Comment: I really do appreciate the help guys. Thanks @Zeta for that valgrind tip, haven't used that one yet.